# Entity Framework 5 Multiple identity columns specified for table. Only one identity column per table is allowed

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am creating this model as part of my code first entity framework

```
public class NewUserRegistration
{
    [Key]
    public int NewUserRegistrationId { get; set; }    
}
```

Using the `Update-Database -Verbose -Force` command in the Package Manger ConsoleI get this exception during the this bit of the update `Applying automatic migration: 201211252223088_AutomaticMigration.`

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[NewUserRegistration] ADD [NewUserRegistrationId]
>   [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Multiple identity columns specified for table
>   'NewUserRegistration'. Only one identity column per table is allowed. 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction
>   transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction
>   transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean
>   downgrading, Boolean auto)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String
>   migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean
>   downgrading)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String
>   migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean
>   downgrading)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   ClientConnectionId:a39395da-5f2b-48e0-bdac-b48d75a68c68 Multiple
>   identity columns specified for table 'NewUserRegistration'. Only one
>   identity column per table is allowed.

There is plainly only one Identity Column specified. So why is this the case?

When I do this I get no exception.

```
public class NewUserRegistration
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }    
}
```

Any thoughts on why this is the case?

***EDIT***

I should say that I am changing the name of the key. The comments say that you can't just do this. How can I drop and recreate?

Is it best to delete the database from SQL and then just run the `Update-Database` command again?

Comment: Looks like you are changing existing table. Did you have other key in the entity before you added `NewUserRegistrationId`? Identity columns cannot be simply changed.

Comment: yes, so how do I instruct the thing to drop and recreate the table.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I encountered the same error when trying to rename a Key column. To make the migration work, I had to reorder the order of operations in my scaffolded migration script.

Here, I made sure to order the Drop operations first, then added the new Key field afterwards.

```
public partial class RenameKey : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.GameSummary", new[] { "OldId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.GameSummary", "OldId");
        AddColumn("dbo.GameSummary", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.GameSummary", "Id");
    }
```

Comment: One might think that DropPrimaryKey would be sufficient. When reordering the code, ensure both DropPrimaryKey & DropColumn occur prior to AddColumn with ColumnBuilder type method which includes identity: true.

Comment: But that does not work with existing data in the OldId column right?

Comment: Strange that EF does not anticipate this and you have to manually do that

Comment: I've provided an answer on Mar 13 '14 that avoids loss of existing data.

Answer (score 7):

I also didn't have any problem simply replacing the relevant `DropPrimaryKey`, `DropColumn`, `AddColumn` and `AddPrimaryKey` commands with a `RenameColumn` command, e.g.

```
public partial class RenameKey : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {    
        RenameColumn("dbo.GameSummary", "OldId", "Id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. May be a graceful way to deal with existing data.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem after my first migrations. What I realized was that after I deleted the database which the first migration created and then too removed the migrations folder created in my mvc application, the problem did not appear again.

Answer (score 2):

first `Add-Migration -Name` 
then

```
public override void Up()
{    
    RenameColumn("dbo.Department", "OldId", "NewId");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the name of the column directly from the class using something like this:

```
[Column("ProductID")]
```

Example:

```
namespace Z_Market.Models
{
    public  class Product
    {
        [Key, Column("ProductID")]  //This change the name of the column when you are using migration.  If you have a form created already, you have to change the connection in the for to aim the new column name.  
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastBuy { get; set; }
        public float Stock { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public string deleteme { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SupplierProduct> SupplierProducts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this answer for EF5 or EF6?

Answer (score 0):

The best implementatios was:

```
/*Replace*/
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.GameSummary", new[] { "OldId" });
DropColumn("dbo.GameSummary", "OldId");
AddColumn("dbo.GameSummary", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
AddPrimaryKey("dbo.GameSummary", "Id");
/*For*/
RenameColumn("dbo.GameSummary", "OldId", "Id");
```