# Unable to use update-database MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to migrate my MVC4 Models to a database with Code First EF 6.  When I run the "update-database" command, I get an error message

> Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Conference'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.

I looked at the Migration file and tried moving around the statements so that they wouldn't be trying to add 2 identity columns on one table and got this.

> Cannot find the object "dbo.foo" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

So what I figured I would try next is to drop all of the migrations and redo the whole process  When I tried the `enable-migrations -contexttypename` command I got this

> Detected database created with a database initializer

When I look at the initial migration, it looks like a migration that I used initially before I got other pieces of the project, missing several of the models.  Then when I add a migration, my problem repeats from the start of this post.

I've exhausted everything I know about MVC4 and my teacher hasn't shown very much interest in helping to figure it out.  Can someone please provide some insight?

Here's the model

```
public class Conference
{
    [Key]
    public int conferenceID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sponsor> Sponsors{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

I removed all of the html and validation metatags to make it easier to read

Comment: this isn't an MVC problem, this is an Entity Framework problem. Show us your model? You probably have more than one [primarykey] set or whatever it's called

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a different configuration in your DbContext class, or you have an EntityTypeConfiguration class in your OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just because you played around with the PK.

Try this: [Same issue but on EF5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556243/entity-framework-5-multiple-identity-columns-specified-for-table-only-one-ident)