# In Entity framework 6, It throws multiple identity columns error even though I have one primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am new to MVC and I am trying to design database using code-first approach. I have read the following thread: [Entity Framework 5 Multiple identity columns specified for table. Only one identity column per table is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556243/entity-framework-5-multiple-identity-columns-specified-for-table-only-one-ident) 
But I believe this is for previous MVC as the current one does not have the following methods as explained the author of the answer. I am getting following error :

> ```
> PM> update-database
> Cannot determine a valid start-up project. Using project 'Project_Zyoos' instead. Your configuration file and working directory
> ```
>
> may not be set as expected. Use the -StartUpProjectName parameter to
>   set one explicitly. Use the -Verbose switch for more information.
>       Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>       No pending explicit migrations.
>       Applying automatic migration: 201804030625539_AutomaticMigration.
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Tournament'. Only one identity column per
>   table is allowed.
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
>   migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
>   transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations,
>   IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel,
>   Boolean downgrading)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel,
>   Boolean downgrading)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>          at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)
>       ClientConnectionId:7c9c5b36-8178-4bf9-bade-80c33d43103f
>       Error Number:2744,State:2,Class:16
>       Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Tournament'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.
>   Code is writtern below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project_Zyoos.Entities
{
    [Table("Tournament")]
    public class Tournament
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Tournament_Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)][Required]
        public string Tournament_Title { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2048)]
        public string Tournament_Description { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Something fishy is going on this migration, `201804030625539_AutomaticMigration.cs`.

Comment: Please post the code of this migration (201804030625539_AutomaticMigration.cs).

Comment: I can't seem to find anything related 201804030625539_AutomaticMigration.cs . There is only one migration folder with   public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        } and protected override void seed(){Project_Zyoos.Models.ApplicationDbContext context} method

Answer (score 0):

It seems like startup project is conflicting may be you have to choose the Default project name to current project(a small dropdown box top of command prompt in nuget package manager) and then update your database through update command or else you have to specify all you parameter manually bellow command:

```
Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [- 
Script] [-Force] 
[-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [- 
ConfigurationTypeName <String>] 
-ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> 
[-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Description
Updates the database to the current model by applying pending migrations.

Parameters
**-SourceMigration** 
Only valid with -Script. Specifies the name of a particular migration to use as the update’s starting point. If ommitted, the last applied migration in the database will be used.

**-TargetMigration** 
Specifies the name of a particular migration to update the database to. If ommitted, the current model will be used.

**-Script**
Generate a SQL script rather than executing the pending changes directly.

**-Force**
Specifies that data loss is acceptable during automatic migration of the database.

**-ProjectName** 
Specifies the project that contains the migration configuration type to be used. If ommitted, the default project selected in package manager console is used.

**-StartUpProjectName** 
Specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If omitted, the specified project’s configuration file is used.

**-ConfigurationTypeName** 
Specifies the migrations configuration to use. If omitted, migrations will attempt to locate a single migrations configuration type in the target project.

**-ConnectionStringName** 
Specifies the name of a connection string to use from the application’s configuration file.

**-ConnectionString** 
Specifies the the connection string to use. If omitted, the context’s default connection will be used.

**-ConnectionProviderName** 
Specifies the provider invariant name of the connection string.

**-AppDomainBaseDirectory** 
Specifies the directory to use for the app-domain that is used for running Migrations code such that the app-domain is able to find all required assemblies. This is an advanced option that should only be needed if the solution contains several projects such that the assemblies needed for the context and configuration are not all referenced from either the project containing the context or the project containing the migrations.

This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug, ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable, OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable.

you can also get help like in package manager console:

```
 get-help Update-Database -full
```